# how to slice td limit by 2 in table angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a `carsList` array having 5 values. i try `slice` 2 by 2

```
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="#item of carsList | slice:0:2; #i = index">
                   <td>{{i}}. {{item}}</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

above code split 2 values only. I want slice 2 by 2.

```
 Example 

      0   1
      2   3
      4   5
```

Code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/BZnaSIldgO3Dmwao1mo6?p=preview

kindly help me . where is my mistake.

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/Z5dWFcmY2BoLlUd7MqOy/ Is this working?

Comment: Please check now. https://plnkr.co/edit/BZnaSIldgO3Dmwao1mo6?p=preview

Comment: Still doesn't work, probably because of a firewall issue but Jsfiddle works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`slice` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) results an array with 2 elements and [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor) would iterate over the elements in the resulted array, that doesn't provide the expected result.

To achieve the result either you need to convert the array structure or do something like this with an additional [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) with nested [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor).

```
<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="#item of carsList; #i = index">
    <tr *ngIf="i % 2 === 0">
      <td *ngFor="#item1 of carsList|slice:i:i + 2; #i1 = index" class="car-title">{{i1}}. {{item1}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

or by removing nested [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor) and simply creating 2 `td` manually.

```
<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="#item of carsList; #i = index">
    <tr *ngIf="i %2 === 0">
      <td>{{i}}. {{item}}</td>
      <td>{{ i + 1 }}. {{carsList[i + 1]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

**FYI :** Where [`ng-container`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngcontainer) can be used to group element which doesn't put in the DOM tree.

Updated [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Vuk4SpTGPkXviJURvbw?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Pranav's answer almost conveyed the idea for achieving it, however his plunker seemed to not show exactly what the OP had, in addition to looking a bit over-complicated.

A simple fix as per the plunker in OP would be this (confirmed it to be working there),

```
<ul>
 <ng-container *ngFor="#item of carsList; #i = index">
  <li *ngIf="i % 2 === 0">
   <span class="car-title">{{i}}. {{item}}</span>
  </li>
 </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
<ul>
 <ng-container *ngFor="#item of carsList; #i = index">
  <li *ngIf="i % 2 === 0">
   <span class="car-title">{{i}}. {{item}}</span>
   <span class="car-title">{{i+1}}. {{carsList[i + 1]}}</span>
  </li>
 </ng-container>
</ul>
```